# Singularities of $f$; order of pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, singularity

> $$f(z):= \frac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1 - \sin(\pi z/2)}$$
>
> Classify all singularities of $f$. (p145 Frietag's).

I obtain that singularities are at $z= 1+4k$. Further if $z=1$, we have removable singularity, $z=-3$ we have simple pole and all other singularities are pole of order $2$. I made the substitution $w = z-r$, $r$ is a root, and taylor expand the cosine series.

Frietag's solution states that all singularities are simple other than at $z=1,-3$ which are removable.

Is he right or my proof wrong?

Comment: you are right about $z=-3$ but what is your proof?

Comment: Substitute $z= w+(1+4k)$, then $\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}(w+(1+4k) )=cos(\pi w/2)$, We have a holomorphic with zero of order $2$ in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You are right about $-3$: it is a simple pole, since $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, with $g(z)=(z-1)^2(z+3)=16(z+3)+8(z+3)^2+(z+3)^3$ and $h(z)=1-\sin(\pi z/2)$. Furthermore, $h(-3)=h'(-3)=0$ and $h''(0)\neq0$.